# Bootstrap Date-picker doesn't trigger changeDate event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**aspx**

```aspx
<asp:TextBox class="form-control date-picker" runat="server" ID="txtDate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
</asp:TextBox>
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="icon-calendar bigger-110"></i>
</span>
```

**js**

```
<script>

   $('#txtDate')
          .datepicker()
          .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                alert(":P :P");
                if (ev.date.valueOf() < date - start - display.valueOf()) { alert(":P"); }
  });
</script>
```

Can someone please help me with this. I'm new to bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure bootstrap version and bootstrap datepicker plugin version.The Bootstrap adds 3 attributes to the changeDate event.

```
$('#calendar').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
    alert(e.format());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that's definitely the ID of the text box? If you're using content work areas and master pages in webforms you'll find the ID is prepended with other information.

Try `<%= txtDate.ClientID %>` in your javascript to get the ID the server control will render.

Example:

```
<script>

   $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>")
          .datepicker()
          .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                alert(":P :P");
                if (ev.date.valueOf() < date - start - display.valueOf())                      {alert(":P"); }
  });
</script>
```

That's if your JS is included on that page. Another alternative is set to the ClientIDMode to **static**.